# SSRS RDLC character appears partially hidden in report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I'm new to SSRS reports, and I didn't write this report, I'm just trying to fix it; and I've had no luck searching for anyone else suffering from this (too many false-positive matches).

Part of the data for a field is being rendered in a way that leaves half of the first character invisible. Perhaps the best thing to do is to show a screenshot of the problem (see the data in the final column):

StackOverflow says I don't have enough reputation to embed the image; but it's here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YtcB.png

The "8" character is being chopped in half. I don't understand why the data isn't forced inside the 2pt padding, or why it doesn't split the date value between the date and time.

By the way, I suspect there is little value asking why the penultimate column looks OK: the columns are different widths, and the penultimate column is an expression returning a DateTime whereas the final column has to handle the possibility of the DateTime being null.

The RDLC file is here (requires you to download the file; suggestions of a better alternative are welcome): http://www.filedropper.com/markerprogresssummarybycomponent

Comment: adding a second example, where the same problem occurs on the penultimate column of the same report:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/yNd2g.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's attempting to fit as much of the date/time on the same line without wrapping as possible, which doesn't necessarily fit in that cell.

2 Suggestions:

1. Increase the width/padding of the cells that are cutting off text so the
   entire date/time fits
2. If it's not a problem to have the time shown on the next line, you could force it to wrap at the time part, thus eliminating the issue:

   =Replace("8/6/2015 12:35:02 PM", " ", chr(10), 1, 1)

Comment: Thanks for your pragmatic suggestions. We've only started using SSRS comparatively recently; so I'd be disappointed if ended up being the accepted solution. It implies that the technology could fail this way on any field in any report; and that reports have to be re-worked each time a different combination of data caused a problem. (And with no way of knowing if you are re-introducing a problem that you've previously fixed.)

Comment: Option 1 doesn't appeal because this particular report is the "en-US" version of the report (hence the timestamp format); but it could be used in different locales (we support several) - I wouldn't want to have to change column widths based on the worst case of any locale.

Option 2 doesn't appeal because I want the renderer to take responsibility for deciding the size of the box for the value. I don't want to force it onto two lines if the renderer can fit it on one.